# How to turn off source XSD for XML files in VSCode

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xsd

How do you turn off annoying XSD source that is constantly popping on mouse hover in XML files in VSCode.

[image: Annoying pop up]

[image: My plugins]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in [vscode-xml 0.12.0](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/issues/258). Empty popup won't show up if there's no documentation.

If you want to disable hover completely for xml files, you can add this preference setting in vscode:

```
  "[xml]":{
    "editor.hover.enabled": false
  }
```